# In the Settings/Apple ID section, I get an error message: “Trusted devices list is not available”. What would cause this?

Tags: ipad, apple-id, ipados

On my iPad Air (3rd generation), when I go into Settings, then tap my name, in the Apple ID section I get an error message:  “Trusted devices list is not available”.  What would cause this?

Comment: Try logging out of iCloud, then log back in.

Answer (score 1):

I access the Internet only via cellular service (I don’t have wifi access).  I discovered that I had disabled Settings from using cellular service.  After enabling it, my problem went away.